# Пытаюсь сделать эквалайзер сигнала с помощью адаптивной фильтрации на Matlab/python

Tags: python, matlab

Пытаюсь научиться применять эквалайзер для уменьшения влияния канала. Изначально у меня был код из лабораторной работы, реализованный с помощью алгоритмов matlab:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

% Experiment parameters:
Algorithm = 0;  % Algorithm = 0 - MI RLS, Algorithm = 1 - NLMS,Algorithm = 2 - LMS
equalizer_length = 35; % Equalizer length
Delay =16;      % Approx. delay by channel + half length of equalizer
lambda=0.995;   % RLS forgetting parameter, 0 < lambda <= 1 
delta=1000;     % Inverse correlation matrix regularization
mu_nlms = 0.4;  % NLMS adaptive filter step-size
epsilon = 1e-6; % NLMS offset
mu_lms=0.001;   % LMS adaptive filter step-size

MDL=1;                   % Modulation: MDL=0 - QAM, MDL=1 - PSK
MC = 8;                 % Constellation - alphabet dimention: number of different symbols. Choose from 4/16/64/256
Ini_Phase = 0.;          % Initial phase
Symbol_Order = 'bin';    % 'bin' or 'gray'(see MATLAB "Help")
K_training = 500;        % Training sequence length, samples
K_decision = 5000;       % Decision sequence length, samples
SNR = 30;                % Channel output signal-to-noise ratio, SNR, dB
FFTA=512;                % FFT length in points, used for frequency response calculation

varian=5; % variant

rand('state',varian);    % Initialization of rand generator
randn('state',varian);   % Initialization of randn generator 

%Channel impulse response
channel = [0.5 1.2 1.5 -1]; % Channel 
K_symbols = K_training+K_decision;      % Total number of symbols
train_data = zeros(1,K_training+Delay); % Training data
s = zeros(K_symbols,1);                 % Total number of modulated data
hat_s = zeros(K_symbols,1);             % Adaptive filter output

% Modulation alphabet
if MDL == 0
    symbol = constel_qam(MC,Ini_Phase);
else MDL == 1
    symbol = constel_psk(MC,Ini_Phase);
end

% Training data
s=zeros(K_symbols,1);
s(1:K_training)=(sign(randn(1,K_training))+j*sign(randn(1,K_training)))/(sqrt(2)); 
train_data(Delay+1:K_training+Delay)=s(1:K_training); % training data

% Decisisoon data
x=rand(K_decision,1);
xint=round((MC-1)*x); % generates integers, e.g., between 0 and MC-1
if MDL == 0
    s(K_training+1:K_symbols) = qammod(xint,MC,Ini_Phase,Symbol_Order); % modulation
elseif MDL == 1
    s(K_training+1:K_symbols) = pskmod(xint,MC,Ini_Phase,Symbol_Order);
else
    s(K_training+1:K_symbols) = dpskmod(xint,MC,Ini_Phase,Symbol_Order);
end

y=filter(channel,1,s); % filters data through channel

sigma_v_dd = sqrt(var(y(1:K_training))/10^(SNR/10)) % during decision-directed
sigma_v_tt = sqrt(var(y(K_training+1:end))/10^(SNR/10)) % during training

v=zeros(K_symbols,1);
v(1:K_training)=(sigma_v_tt/sqrt(2))*(randn(1,K_training)+1i*randn(1,K_training));
v(K_training+1:K_symbols)=(sigma_v_dd/sqrt(2))*(randn(1,K_symbols-K_training)+1i*randn(1,K_symbols-K_training));

SNR_training=10*log10(var(y(1:K_training))/var(v(1:K_training)))
SNR_decission=10*log10(var(y(K_training+1:end))/var(v(K_training+1:end)))

r=y+v; 

% Equalizer initialization
w  = zeros(equalizer_length,1); % equalizer coefficients (column) 
u  = zeros(1,equalizer_length); % regressor vector (row) 
e = zeros(K_symbols,1);         % error vector
num_errors=0;

%  Adaptive Equalization

if Algorithm == 0 % RLS algorithm is used
    
    Alg='RLS';
    P=delta*eye(equalizer_length,equalizer_length);
    lambda_inv=1/lambda;
    
    % Training mode
    for i = 1:K_training+Delay
        u  = [r(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
        hat_s(i) = u*w;
        e(i) = train_data(i)- hat_s(i);
        gamma = 1 + lambda_inv*u*P*u';
        P = lambda_inv*(P-(lambda_inv*P*u'*u*P/gamma));
        w=w+P*u'*e(i);
    end
%     figure
    clc;
    disp(train_data(20:30))
    disp(s(20:30))
    
    scatterplot(hat_s)
    
    % Decision-directed mode
    for i = K_training+Delay+1:K_symbols
        u  = [r(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
        hat_s(i) = u*w;
        check_s(i)=slicer(hat_s(i),symbol);
        e(i) = check_s(i) - hat_s(i);
        gamma = 1 + lambda_inv*u*P*u';
        P = lambda_inv*(P-(lambda_inv*P*u'*u*P/gamma));
        w=w+P*u'*e(i);
        if (check_s(i) ~= s(i-Delay))
            num_errors = num_errors + 1;
        end
    end  
    
elseif Algorithm == 1 % NLMS algorithm is used
    
    Alg='NLMS';

    % Training mode
    for i = 1:K_training+Delay
        u  = [r(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
        hat_s(i) = u*w;
        e(i) = train_data(i)- hat_s(i);
        w = w + mu_nlms*e(i)*u'/(norm(u)^2+epsilon);
    end
    
    % Decision-directed mode
    for i = K_training+Delay+1:K_symbols
        u  = [r(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
        hat_s(i) = u*w;
        check_s(i)=slicer(hat_s(i),symbol);
        d(i) = check_s(i); % decision_directed
        e(i) = d(i)- hat_s(i);
        w = w + mu_nlms*e(i)*u'/(norm(u)^2+epsilon);
        if (check_s(i) ~= s(i-Delay))
            num_errors = num_errors + 1;
        end
    end

else % LMS algorithm is used
    
    Alg='LMS';
    
    % Training mode
    for i = 1:K_training+Delay
        u  = [r(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
        hat_s(i) = u*w;
        d(i) = train_data(i); % training
        e(i) = d(i)- hat_s(i);
        w = w + mu_lms*e(i)*u';
    end
    
    % Decision-directed mode
    for i = K_training+Delay+1:K_symbols
        u  = [r(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
        hat_s(i) = u*w;
        check_s(i)=slicer(hat_s(i),symbol);
        d(i) = check_s(i); % decision_directed
        e(i) = d(i)- hat_s(i);
        w = w + mu_lms*e(i)*u';
        if (check_s(i) ~= s(i-Delay))
            num_errors = num_errors + 1;
        end
    end

end

num_errors

% Scatterplots of last samples of all signal
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
scatterplot1(y(K_training+Delay+1:K_symbols), hat_s(K_training+Delay+1:K_symbols), s(K_training+Delay+1:K_symbols), ...
    1, 0, '.g' ,'.m', '.b')
xlabel('Re ( a_{i} )','Color','k','FontSize',12,'FontName','Arial Unicode MS')
ylabel('Im ( a_{i} )','Color','k','FontSize',12,'FontName','Arial Unicode MS')
title(['All constellations, ',Alg,' Algorithm'],'FontSize',12,'FontName','Arial Unicode MS')
set(gca,'FontSize',12,'FontName','Arial Unicode MS')
grid on
legend('Channel','Equalized','Data');
```

Чтобы запустить его, нужны дополнительные функции:

```
function y=slicer(x,symbol)
 
% The software is developed  by Victor I. Djigan
% Last modification: July 20, 2012
% ----------------------------------------------
 
distan = abs(x-symbol);
[a,ind]=min(distan);
y=symbol(ind);
```

```
function symbol=constel_psk(M,Ini_Phase)
 
% The software is developed  by Victor I. Djigan
% Last modification: July 20, 2012
% ----------------------------------------------
 
data=[0:M-1];
modmap = 2*pi*(0:M-1)/M+Ini_Phase;
symbol = exp(j*modmap);
```

```
function symbol=constel_qam(M,Ini_Phase)
 
% The software is developed  by Victor I. Djigan
% Last modification: July 20, 2012
% ----------------------------------------------
 
data=[0:M-1];
symbol = qammod(data,M);
```

Код из лабы замечательно работает, и мне захотелось переделать его под другую задачу, но уже в питоне. Сначала я задаю начальные условия и функции, с которыми буду работать:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from scipy.signal import butter,filtfilt
import time

#INITIAL------------------------------------------------------------------
f=1e3                   # carrier freq
a=1                     # amplitude
lam=0.995               # RLS forgetting parameter, 0 < lambda <= 1 
delta=1000              # Inverse correlation matrix regularization
K_training=256          # Training sequence length, samples
K_decision=1024*2       # Decision sequence length, samples
Delay=21                # Approx. delay by channel + half length of equalizer
MC=8                    # Modulation type
MCT=2                   # Modulation type (training)
equalizer_length=40     # Equalizer length
fd=8*f                  # Discretisation freq
pi=3.14                 # Pi number
fact=0.001

#FUNCTIONS----------------------------------------------------------------
def nextpow2(i):
    a=math.log2(i)
    a=math.ceil(a)
    a=2**a
    return a 

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order):
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

def slicer(x,simb):
    distan=np.abs(x-simb)
    ind=np.argmin(distan)
    return simb[ind]

def scalar(v1,v2):
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        sum=v1[i]*v2[i]+sum
    return sum

def corr(data, fact):
    np1=0
    for x in Quad:
        for y in P2:
            if (x<y+y*fact and x>y-y*fact):
                np2+=1
    np2=0  
    for x in Quad:
        for y in P4:
            if (x<y+y*fact and x>y-y*fact):
                np4+=1
    if np2>=np4:
        ans='BPSK'
    else:
        np1=0 
        for x in Quad:
            for y in P8:
                if (x<y+y*fact and x>y-y*fact):
                    np1+=1
        if np2>=np1:
            ans='QPSK'
        else:
            np2=0 
            for x in Quad:
                for y in P16:
                    if (x<y+y*fact and x>y-y*fact):
                        np2+=1
            if np1>=np2:
                ans='8PSK'
            else:
                np1=0 
                for x in Quad:
                    for y in P32:
                        if (x<y+y*fact and x>y-y*fact):
                            np1+=1
                if np2>=np1:
                    ans='16PSK'
                else:
                    np2=0 
                    for x in Quad:
                        for y in P64:
                            if (x<y+y*fact and x>y-y*fact):
                                np2+=1
                    if np1>=np2:
                        ans='32PSK'
                    else:
                        ans='64PSK'
    return ans

#UTILITY------------------------------------------------------------------
start_time = time.time()

ne=nextpow2(K_decision+K_training+Delay)
t=np.linspace(0,(ne-1)/fd,ne)
n=np.array([random.random() for i in range(len(t))])
n=n-0.5*n
SNR=30
K_symbols=K_training+K_decision+Delay
n=n*a/(10**(SNR/10))
```

Затем я хочу притвориться, будто принимаю сигнал с приёмника. Для имитации этого сигнала я делаю вот это:

```
#SIGNAL GENERATOR---------------------------------------------------------
phi=[]
k=int(len(t)/64)
for i in range(k):
    p=random.randint(0,MC)*pi/MC*2
    p=np.ones(64)*p
    phi.extend(p)
phi=np.array(phi)
signal_true=a*np.sin(2*pi*f*t+phi)+n

phi_t=[]
for i in range(k):
    p=random.randint(0,MCT)*pi/MCT*2
    p=np.ones(64)*p
    phi_t.extend(p)
phi_t=np.array(phi_t)
signal_train=a*np.sin(2*pi*f*t+phi_t)+n

#QUADRATURES-------------------------------------------------------------
Q=signal_true*np.sin(2*pi*f*t)
I=signal_true*np.cos(2*pi*f*t)

Qt=signal_train*np.sin(2*pi*f*t)
It=signal_train*np.cos(2*pi*f*t)

#LOWPASS FILTER----------------------------------------------------------
T = 1/fd            # Sample Period
fs = fd             # sample rate, Hz
cutoff = f*1.6      # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz , slightly higher than actual 1.2 Hz
nyq = 0.5 * fs      # Nyquist Frequency
order=10            # filter order

Q = butter_lowpass_filter(Q, cutoff, fs, order)
I = butter_lowpass_filter(I, cutoff, fs, order)
Quad=Q+I*1j
Quad=Quad[0:K_decision+Delay]

Qt = butter_lowpass_filter(Qt, cutoff, fs, order)
It = butter_lowpass_filter(It, cutoff, fs, order)
Quad_train=Qt+It*1j
Quad_train=Quad_train[0:K_training]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t, Qt)
ax.plot(t, It)
ax.set_title('Filtered quadratures')
ax.set_xlim([0, 400/fd])
ax.set_xlabel('Time [seconds]')
ax.set_ylabel('A')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.grid()
plt.show()

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(I, Q)
ax.set_title('Constellation')
ax.set_xlabel('I')
ax.set_ylabel('Q')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

А затем всё как в лабораторной работе (по крайней мере я на это надеюсь):

```
#MODULATION ALPHABET------------------------------------------------------
prep=np.linspace(0,MCT-1,MCT)*2*pi/MCT
aa=max(np.real(Q))
print(aa)
simbol=aa*(np.cos(prep)+np.sin(prep)*1j)

#TRAINING DATA------------------------------------------------------------
sig=[]
sig.extend(Quad_train)
sig.extend(Quad)

P=delta*np.eye(equalizer_length,equalizer_length)
lambda_inv=1/lam

w=np.zeros(equalizer_length)*1j
w=w.reshape(-1,1)
u=np.zeros(equalizer_length)*1j
e=np.zeros(K_symbols)*1j
e=e.reshape(-1,1)

#DJIGA--------------------------------------------------------------------
sigma_v_dd=math.sqrt((np.var(Quad_train)/10)**(SNR/10))
sigma_v_tt=math.sqrt((np.var(Quad)/10)**(SNR/10))

v=np.zeros(K_symbols)*1j
v[0:K_training]=sigma_v_tt/math.sqrt(2)*(np.random.normal(size=(1,K_training))+np.random.normal(size=(1,K_training))*1j)
v[K_training:K_symbols]=sigma_v_dd/math.sqrt(2)*(np.random.normal(size=(1,K_symbols-K_training))+np.random.normal(size=(1,K_symbols-K_training))*1j)

SNR_training=10*np.log10(np.var(Quad_train)/np.var(v[0:K_training]))
SNR_decision=10*np.log10(np.var(Quad)/np.var(v[K_training:K_symbols]))

Quad=v[K_training:K_symbols]+Quad
Quad_train=v[0:K_training]+Quad_train
Quad_train=list(Quad_train)
Quad_train.extend(Quad[0:Delay])
Quad_train=np.array(Quad_train)
Quad=list(Quad)
Quad[0:Delay]=[]
Quad=np.array(Quad)

#TRAINING MODE------------------------------------------------------------
hat_s=np.zeros(K_training+Delay)*1j
hat_s=hat_s.reshape(-1,1)

for i in range(K_training+Delay):
    u=list(u[0:equalizer_length-1])
    u.insert(0,Quad_train[i])
    u=np.array(u)
    ur=u.reshape(-1,1)
    ur=ur.conjugate()
    hat_s[i]=scalar(u,w)
    if i<=Delay:
        e[i]=-hat_s[i]
    else:
        e[i]=slicer(hat_s[i], simbol)-hat_s[i]
    u=u.reshape(equalizer_length,)
    A=np.dot(u,P)
    gamma=1+lambda_inv*scalar(A,ur)
    A=np.dot(P,ur)
    A=scalar(A,u)
    P=lambda_inv*P-(lambda_inv*A*P/gamma)
    w=w+np.dot(P,ur)*e[i]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.real(hat_s), np.imag(hat_s), 'bo')
ax.plot(np.real(Quad_train), np.imag(Quad_train), 'ro')
ax.set_title('Test equalized')
ax.set_xlabel('I')
ax.set_ylabel('Q')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.grid()
plt.show()

del hat_s

# DECISION MODE------------------------------------------------------------
hat_s=np.zeros(K_decision)*1j
hat_s=hat_s.reshape(-1,1)
check_s=[]

for i in range(K_decision):
    u=list(u[0:equalizer_length-1])
    u.insert(0,Quad[i])
    u=np.array(u)
    ur=u.reshape(-1,1)
    ur=ur.conjugate()
    hat_s[i]=scalar(u,w)
    A=np.dot(u,P)
    gamma=1+lambda_inv*np.dot(A,ur)
    A=np.dot(P,ur)
    A=scalar(A,u)
    P=lambda_inv*P-(lambda_inv*A*P/gamma)
    w=w+np.dot(P,ur)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(np.real(hat_s), np.imag(hat_s))
ax.set_title('Constellation equalized')
ax.set_xlabel('I')
ax.set_ylabel('Q')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.grid()
plt.show()

##END--------------------------------------------------------------------
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Но код выдаёт полную чушь, эквализированное созвездие растекается даже больше, чем то, которое изначально было "принято". В итоге влияние канала компенсировать не выходит.
Чтобы убедиться в том, что код не работает не из-за специфики питона (мало знаком с этим языком), я решил перенести его обратно в матлаб:

```
clc; clear all; close all;
f=1e3;
a=1;
lam=0.995;
delta=1000;
K_training=256;
K_decision=1024*2;
Delay=21;
equalizer_length=40;
fd=8*f;
fact=0.001;
MC=8;
MCT=2;

ne=2^nextpow2(K_decision+K_training);
t=0:1/fd:(ne-1)/fd;
n=rand(1,length(t));
n=n-0.5*n;
SNR=30;
K_symbols=K_training+K_decision+Delay;
n=n*a/(10^(SNR/10));

phi=[];
k=length(t)/64;
for i=1:k
    p=randi([0 MC])*pi/MC*2;
    p=ones(1,64)*p;
    phi=[phi p];
end
signal_true=a*sin(2*pi*f*t+phi);

phi_t=[];
for i=1:k
    p=randi([1 MCT])*pi/MCT*2;
    p=ones(1,64)*p;
    phi_t=[phi_t p];
end
signal_train=a*sin(2*pi*f*t+phi_t);

Q=signal_true.*sin(2*pi*f*t);
I=signal_true.*cos(2*pi*f*t);

Qt=signal_train.*sin(2*pi*f*t);
It=signal_train.*cos(2*pi*f*t);

T=1/fd;
[b a]=butter(6, f/fd*2, 'low');
Q=filter(b,a,Q);
Qt=filter(b,a,Qt);
I=filter(b,a,I);
It=filter(b,a,It);

figure
plot(Q)
hold on;
plot(I);
grid on;

Quad=Q+I*j;
Quad=Quad(1:K_decision+Delay);
Quad_train=Qt+It*j;
Quad_train=Quad_train(1:K_training);

figure
hold on;
plot(Quad,'*r')
plot(Quad_train, '*b')
grid on;

aa=max(real(Q));
prep=[0 1]*pi;
simbol=aa*(cos(prep)+sin(prep)*j);

sig=[];
sig=[Quad Quad_train];
P=delta*eye(equalizer_length);
lambda_inv=1/lam;

w=zeros(equalizer_length,1);
u=zeros(1,equalizer_length);
e=zeros(K_symbols,1);

sigma_v_dd=sqrt(var(Quad_train)/10)^(SNR/10);
sigma_v_tt=sqrt(var(Quad)/10)^(SNR/10);
v=zeros(1,K_symbols);
v(1:K_training)=(sigma_v_tt/sqrt(2))*(randn(1,K_training)+1i*randn(1,K_training));
v(K_training+1:K_symbols)=(sigma_v_dd/sqrt(2))*(randn(1,K_symbols-K_training)+1i*randn(1,K_symbols-K_training));

Quad=v(K_training+1:K_symbols)+Quad;
Quad_train=v(1:K_training);
Quad_train=[Quad_train Quad(1:Delay)];
Quad(1:Delay)=[];

hat_s=zeros(K_training+Delay,1);
for i=1:K_training+Delay
    u=[Quad_train(i) u(1:equalizer_length-1)];
    hat_s(i)=u*w;
    if i<=Delay
        e(i)=hat_s(i);
    else
        distan=abs(hat_s(i)-simbol);
        [xmin,ind]=min(distan);
        e(i)=simbol(ind)-hat_s(i);
    end
    gamma = 1 + lambda_inv*u*P*u';
    P = lambda_inv*(P-(lambda_inv*P*u'*u*P/gamma));
    w=w+P*u'*e(i);
end

figure
hold on;
plot(real(hat_s),imag(hat_s),'.r');
plot(real(Quad_train),imag(Quad_train),'.b');
grid on;
```

И... он не работает и там! Уже долгое время сравниваю лабораторную работу со своим кодом, пытаясь найти ошибку, но ничего не выходит. Вдруг здесь кто-то может помочь? Вполне возможно, что я допустил какую-то тупую ошибку и просто не вижу её.